# Unqualified Class Name Collides with New .NET Class in System Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I have (a *lot*) of legacy code that references one of my static classes, called `AppContext`.  Sadly, references to this class have all been resolved in this legacy code by a namespace `using` declaration throughout.  For the sake of argument, let's say the namespace is "MyNamespace" (it isn't, but it's just as bad)

Therefore, I have many, many modules that start off looking like this:

```
using System;
using MyNamespace;
```

My problem now is that Microsoft, in their .NET Framework 4.6, has introduced a new `System.AppContext` class.  Obviously, all of my code uses `System`.

Now whenever I get to a line of code that looks something like this:

```
if (AppContext.MyProperty == "some value")
```

... I will get an error telling me that *MyProperty* is not a recognized member of AppContext.

**Now as my users roll out Windows updates containing .NET 4.6 (or .NET 4.6.1) I find my distributed code is breaking all over the place.**

I know that my brute force solution to this is to go to every place where I reference my class and apply an unambiguous namespace.  This is a sensible thing to do and I will do it going forward.  My problem is that I have a big installed base and fixing this everywhere for everyone will take a lot of time and a lot of work (especially considering regression testing/moving to production, etc.)

**Is there any way to resolve the name conflict, short of adding an unambiguous namespace to each reference of my class?**

I'd really like to know if there is a quick/short term solution that I can use to keep my users from breaking my system with Windows updates until I can get a proper solution rolled out everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `using AppContext = MyNamespace.AppContext` to the top of every file.

Comment: Thanks (+1).  A type alias will help to a great extent, since I can make one change at the top of each code file, rather than changing each reference to the static class (AppContext).  I'm hoping though that there is something else that can be done, perhaps at the assembly level.  I have hundreds of code files to touch.  I'm looking for a very fast stop gap to avoid as many production outages as possible.